# I want to be able to add variables to themselves so they match the value I assigned them

Tags: c, variables, while-loop

I want to be able to give as many prices as I want and when I end the loop it will write the sum of all the prices, so I later can convert the sum to SEK currency. In the assigment I should be able to add a new price as long as it is over 0.

```
while (price < 0) {
   printf("Give price (finish with <0) :\n");
   scanf("%lf", &price );

   if (price < 0) {
     printf("Sum in foreign currency: %lf\n", sum);
   }
}
```

This is how my code should work:

```
Your shopping assistant

1. Set exchange rate in SEK (current rate: 1.00)
2. Read prices in the foreign currency
3. End

Give your choice (1 - 3): 1

Give exchange rate: 9.71

1. Set exchange rate in SEK (current rate: 9.71)
2. Read prices in the foreign currency
3. End

Give your choice (1 - 3): 4

Not a valid choice!!

1. Set exchange rate in SEK (current rate: 9.71)
2. Read prices in the foreign currency
3. End

Give your choice (1 - 3): 2

Give price (finish with <0): 2.75
Give price (finish with <0): 3.50
Give price (finish with <0): -23

Sum in foreign currency: 6.25
Sum in SEK: 60.69

1. Set exchange rate in SEK (current rate: 9.71)
2. Read prices in the foreign currency
3. End

Give your choice (1 - 3): 3

End of program!
```

Comment: You need a data structure that can hold _any_ number of prices. Or does your homework mention a maximum? If not then you can `malloc` an array of prices, remember how large it is and how many elements are in use, and if it is full, `realloc` it to a larger size.

Answer (score 0):

- The loop should execute while the `price` non-negative, and the check should be done at the end of the loop. At the beginning of the loop, the price is not yet known.
- The `price` is only valid when `scanf` had returned 1, so you need to check that.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double getPriceSum() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    double price;
    do {
        printf("Give price (finish with <0) :\n");
        int num = scanf("%lf", &price);
        if (num != 1)
            price = 0.0; // set a "safe" value for price
        else if (price > 0.0) {
            assert(num == 1); // asserts are like comments that the compiler understands:)
            sum += price;
        }
    } while (price >= 0);

    assert(price < 0); // otherwise the loop wouldn't terminate

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    // ...
    double sum = getPriceSum();
    printf("Sum in foreign currency: %lf\n", sum);
}
```

It'd be much nicer to have the `price` variable declared inside the loop, since it's not needed outside, and then we don't need gymnastics with its initial value set so that the loop won't terminate inadvertently:

```
double getPriceSum() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (;;) { // repeat "forever" unless otherwise exited
        double price;
        printf("Give price (finish with <0) :\n");
        int num = scanf("%lf", &price);
        if (num == 1) {
            if (price >= 0.0)
                sum += price;
            else 
                return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `printf` with `\n` will move the cursor to another line *and* flush the output to screen. You likely don't want the cursor move (per the example output). Instead, remove `\n` and issue an explicit flush:

```
printf("Give price (finish wih <0) : ");
fflush(stdout);
```

It's also possible to be less awkward and accept a word instead of a number as the "exit" command:

```
double getPriceSum() {
    double sum = 0.0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t lineSize = 0;
    for (;;) {
        printf("Give price, or DONE to finish : ");
        fflush(stdout);
        int result = getline(&line, &lineSize, stdin);
        if (result < 0)
            break;
        if (!line || !lineSize)
            continue; // read again
        if (strcmp(line, "DONE") == 0 || strcmp(line, "done") == 0)
            break;
        double price;
        result = sscanf(line, "%lf", &price);
        if (result == 1 && price > 0)
            sum += price;
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "  - Invalid price. Try again.\n");
    }
    return sum;
}
```